# cURL not processing all requests - stops around 110

Tags: php, curl

So I am having trouble getting this code to work. I pulled it from a blog and it is based on the wordpress link checker. I have about 6000 urls in a database i need to check the http status so this seems like a great choice. I've modified the code slightly to fit my needs and it works (kind of).

I have checked the `url_list` array throughout the code and it contains all of the url's. The problem is that it will basically stop executing after about the 110th row, it is kind of random but generally around that number. Not really sure if I need to set a timeout somewhere or if I have a bug in the code. I noticed that if I set `$max_connections` greater than 8 it will return a 500 error. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
// CONFIG
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'test';
$db_pass = 'yearight';
$db_name = 'URLS';
$excluded_domains = array();
$max_connections = 7;

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=URLS', $db_user, $db_pass);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT url FROM list");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

// initialize some variables
$url_list = array();
$working_urls = array();
$dead_urls = array();
$not_found_urls = array();
$active = null;

foreach($result as $d) {
    // get all links via regex
    if (preg_match_all('@((http?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', $d, $matches)) {

        foreach ($matches[1] as $url) {

            // store the url
            $url_list []= $url;
        }
    }
}

// 1. multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

// 2. add multiple URLs to the multi handle
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_connections; $i++) {
    add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list);
}

// 3. initial execution
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

// 4. main loop
while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {

    // 5. there is activity
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {

        // 6. do work
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        // 7. is there info?
        if ($mhinfo = curl_multi_info_read($mh)) {
            // this means one of the requests were finished

            // 8. get the info on the curl handle
            $chinfo = curl_getinfo($mhinfo['handle']);

            // 9. dead link?
            if (!$chinfo['http_code']) {
                $dead_urls []= $chinfo['url'];

            // 10. 404?
            } else if ($chinfo['http_code'] == 404) {
                $not_found_urls []= $chinfo['url'];

            // 11. working
            } else {
                $working_urls []= $chinfo['url'];
            }

            // 12. remove the handle
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $mhinfo['handle']);
            curl_close($mhinfo['handle']);

            // 13. add a new url and do work
            if (add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list)) {

                do {
                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }
        }
    }
}

// 14. finished
curl_multi_close($mh);

echo "==Dead URLs==<br/>";
echo implode("<br/>",$dead_urls) . "<br/><br/>";

echo "==404 URLs==<br>";
echo implode("<br/>",$not_found_urls) . "<br/><br/>";

echo "==Working URLs==<br/>";
echo implode("<br/>",$working_urls);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($url_list); 
echo "</pre>";
// 15. adds a url to the multi handle
function add_url_to_multi_handle($mh, $url_list) {
    static $index = 0;

    // if we have another url to get
    if ($url_list[$index]) {

        // new curl handle
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set the url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_list[$index]);
        // to prevent the response from being outputted
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // follow redirections
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        // do not need the body. this saves bandwidth and time
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

        // add it to the multi handle
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);


        // increment so next url is used next time
        $index++;

        return true;
    } else {

        // we are done adding new URLs
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

I have written a script in bash that does the same thing as this. I notice when I was going through the text file the info was output to, that when it fails it is typically around links that return odd http status codes like `000` and `522` some of them tend to execute for up to 5 minutes! So I am wondering if the PHP version of cURL is stopping execution when it encounters these status codes. It is just a thought and might add more value to help solve the issue.

Comment: How much time the script takes to process around 110 rows?

Comment: @bad_boy around 10 seconds give or take

Comment: shuffle the list so the links at the top are now at the bottom and check again if the problem still occurs generally around the 110th row or not.

Comment: For debugging purposes, try to `echo ini_get('max_execution_time');` What it says?

Comment: @bad_boy the max execution time is `120`

Comment: @haywire I used `shuffle($url_list)` and it executed for longer but would return a 500 error

Comment: @bad_boy I added `set_time_limit(0)` to the first line and now it is returning 0 so It is set to run indefinetely;

Comment: "It will return 500 error" is not a valid problem description. **What** error is logged? Don't guess, look it up. When things don't work, they rarely "just don't work". Normally an error tells you exactly why not.

Comment: When it decides to return 500 it gives this in the error log
`[Thu Aug 21 10:12:34 2014] [warn] [client 73.36.140.198] (110)Connection timed out: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
[Thu Aug 21 10:12:44 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 1237 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
`
The results are sporadic when it does decide to execute the script. For example sometimes it will print 114 results while other times it might print `115`, `117`, `118` I have tried changing multiple variables in the code and settings on the server and it still produces inconsistent results.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 try generating an strace from your cli script to see exactly what it's blocking on...

Comment: @ircmaxell so I used strace on the program and seen a ton of timeouts, `poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)`

Answer (score -1):

1 - EXECUTION TIME ISSUE

2 - DECLAE AT THE TOP OF CODE MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, WILL HELP THIS FOR SURE

bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )